# justify-content works for one div and not for another?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a price component grid, and trying to work out the things with `justify-content` and `align-items`, but I am unable to understand why sometimes the `justify-content` works and sometimes it doesn't.

The below `justify-content` works for lower left part but neither for the upper part nor for the lower right part.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.price-grid {
  margin: 20px auto;
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.upper-part {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  align-items: center;
}

.upperpart-content {
  margin: 0 70px;
}

.upperpart-content h2 {
  color: #533A55;
}

.upperpart-content h3 {
  color: #5F4261;
}

.lower-part {
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
}

.left-part {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #533A55;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.leftpart-content {
  color: white;
}

.leftpart-content>h4 {
  margin-bottom: unset;
}

.leftpart-content span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: unset;
}

.leftpart-content span p {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.leftpart-content>p {
  margin-top: unset;
}

.leftpart-content button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.leftpart-content button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.right-part {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #5F4261;
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  align-items: center;
}

.rightpart-content {
  color: white;
  margin: 0 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="price-grid">
  <div class="upper-part">
    <div class="upperpart-content">
      <h2>Join our community</h2>
      <h3>30-day, hassle-free money back guarantee</h3>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate iusto sit aliquam magni perferendis eum, veritatis nam inventore, dolorum doloremque sed, cum perspiciatis aspernatur facere libero doloribus. Saepe, aperiam odit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lower-part">
    <div class="left-part">
      <div class="leftpart-content">
        <h4>Monthly Subscription</h4>
        <span>
                        <h2>$29</h2>
                        <p>per month</p>
                    </span>
        <p>Full access for less than $1 a day</p>
        <button>Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-part">
      <div class="rightpart-content">
        <h4>Why Us?</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ullam animi totam id obcaecati sed eum nesciunt sit cum! Beatae nam ea ipsa ipsum quasi quidem tempore, quibusdam provident sit rerum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should edit your question title to be more specific to your issue if possible. As phrased now it's very open-ended and might be closed.

Comment: does that seem fine now?

Comment: I don't know, what's your problem, the div in the right part is centered, when you comment out the line. What do you want more? Do you want all items in the right-part-content centered?

Comment: actually what I am looking for is, if you see the left-part, I wanted the content to be centered horizontally as well as vertically, which did happen by the use of both align-items and justify-content. I want the same thing to be in right-part as well as in upper-part, but it does not happen the same way i.e align-items does it job of centering the content vertically but justify-content doesn't make the content centered horizontally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox), the [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) and [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) properties should work as expected (if supported). The reason why your not seeing any position change for the content in `.upper-part` when you modify `justify-content` is because you've made the flex item `.upperpart-content` "stuck" with `margin: 0 70px` so it can't move along the main axis as it only has a limited area to occupy. You notice that changing `align-items` does show a visible position change for flex items on the cross axis, and this is because `height: 50%` gives the flex container enough room to work with so we can easily see changes to alignment of content along the cross axis with `align-items`.

To fix the flexbox situation with `.upper-part`, just give the child container `.upperpart-content` a defined `max-width` with value of `60ch` or whatever you want to mimic the width you created by using `70px` of left and right margin. Now if you alter the `justify-content` property on `.upper-part` you will notice that the content moves along the main axis as expected. This same sort of issue is happening with the lower right container, you have `margin: 0 70px` on `.rightpart-content` and since there is so much text spanning many lines, its occupying all of its available space that is created from the two left/right 70px margins.

If you remove `margin: 0 70px` on `.rightpart-content` and give it some `max-width` just like shown above, then changing `justify-content` on `.right-part` will move the flex items along the main axis. Since the `.left-part` container only has a short amount of text and a button which doesn't occupy 100% of its content box, using `justify-content` works as expected as the main axis has enough "room" for us to notice position changes. There are quite a few things that could be fixed to be "responsive" and use flexbox more efficiently but hopefully this helps you understand why `justify-content` wasn't moving flex items like you expected in those two containers and how you can fix that.

```css
.price-grid
{
    margin: 20px auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.upper-part
{
    height: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.upperpart-content
{
    /* margin: 0 70px; */
    max-width: 60ch; /* vary this */
}
.upperpart-content h2
{
    color: #533A55;
}
.upperpart-content h3
{
    color: #5F4261;
}
.lower-part
{
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
}
.left-part
{
    width: 50%; 
    background-color: #533A55;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.leftpart-content
{
    color: white;
}
.leftpart-content > h4
{
    margin-bottom: unset;
}
.leftpart-content span
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: unset;
}
.leftpart-content span p
{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.leftpart-content > p
{
    margin-top: unset;
}
.leftpart-content button
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.leftpart-content button:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.right-part
{
    width: 50%; 
    background-color: #5F4261;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.rightpart-content
{
    color: white;
    /*margin: 0 70px;*/
    max-width: 35ch; /* Vary this */
}
```

```html
<div class="price-grid">
    <div class="upper-part">
        <div class="upperpart-content">
            <h2>Join our community</h2>
            <h3>30-day, hassle-free money back guarantee</h3>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate iusto sit aliquam magni
                perferendis
                eum, veritatis nam inventore, dolorum doloremque sed, cum perspiciatis aspernatur facere libero
                doloribus. Saepe, aperiam odit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lower-part">
        <div class="left-part">
            <div class="leftpart-content">
                <h4>Monthly Subscription</h4>
                <span>
                    <h2>$29</h2>
                    <p>per month</p>
                </span>
                <p>Full access for less than $1 a day</p>
                <button>Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-part">
            <div class="rightpart-content">
                <h4>Why Us?</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ullam animi totam id obcaecati sed eum
                    nesciunt sit cum! Beatae nam ea ipsa ipsum quasi quidem tempore, quibusdam provident sit rerum.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AkshvirSoni Does this help answer your question? You can now modify the upper container and lower right container with `justify-content` as expected.

Comment: yeah that does help thanks for the answer, I understood that the content was too large for justify-content to show it's affect. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

what I see is that you are having some troubles with the sizing of your content, justify content will center all the items inside your parent, based on the width they have, in the left part, your items are "centered" because the width of those items is really thin, but in the right and upper part, that width is bigger. If you want your content to have kind of the same width as the left part, you need to be specific on that, then, justify-content will work as you expect.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.price-grid {
  margin: 20px auto;
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.upper-part {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.upperpart-content {
  margin: 0 70px;
  width: 70%;
}

.upperpart-content h2 {
  color: #533A55;
}

.upperpart-content h3 {
  color: #5F4261;
}

.lower-part {
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
}

.left-part {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #533A55;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.leftpart-content {
  color: white;
}

.leftpart-content>h4 {
  margin-bottom: unset;
}

.leftpart-content span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: unset;
}

.leftpart-content span p {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.leftpart-content>p {
  margin-top: unset;
}

.leftpart-content button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.leftpart-content button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.right-part {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #5F4261;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
}

.rightpart-content {
  color: white;
  margin: 0 70px;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="price-grid">
  <div class="upper-part">
    <div class="upperpart-content">
      <h2>Join our community</h2>
      <h3>30-day, hassle-free money back guarantee</h3>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate iusto sit aliquam magni perferendis eum, veritatis nam inventore, dolorum doloremque sed, cum perspiciatis aspernatur facere libero doloribus. Saepe, aperiam odit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lower-part">
    <div class="left-part">
      <div class="leftpart-content">
        <h4>Monthly Subscription</h4>
        <span>
                        <h2>$29</h2>
                        <p>per month</p>
                    </span>
        <p>Full access for less than $1 a day</p>
        <button>Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-part">
      <div class="rightpart-content">
        <h4>Why Us?</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ullam animi totam id obcaecati sed eum nesciunt sit cum! Beatae nam ea ipsa ipsum quasi quidem tempore, quibusdam provident sit rerum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, I got it.